# How do I insert into the next available node on a binary search tree?

Tags: java, user-interface, binary-search-tree, nodes

I have a program I need to build where I continue adding to a Binary Search Tree (BST) by opening a file and adding the words from the file to the BST. I have figured out how to open a file and store the words from the original file in the tree, but when I try to open a second file to continue adding to the tree, it just acts as if I am starting from scratch. How do I point to the next available node so that I can continue to insert into it.

I have tried using my insert function, but it just acts as though I'm starting from scratch and deletes everything from the previous file.

My node class:

```
class BSTNode {
    String word;
    int data;
    BSTNode parent;
    BSTNode left;
    BSTNode right;


    public BSTNode(String word, int data) {
        this.word = word;
        this.data = data;
        this.left = null;
        this.right = null;
        this.parent = null;
    }


    public BSTNode() {
    }
}
```

My insert function:

```
  void insert(BSTNode node, String word, int data) {
        if (search(node, word)) {
        } else {
            insertNode(node, word, data);
        }
    }
```

And the button I'm selecting to add another file to the BST:

```
} else if (evt.getSource().equals(anotherFile)) {
                JFileChooser pickFile = new JFileChooser();
                int dialog = pickFile.showOpenDialog(GUI.this);
                if (dialog == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                    GUI.this.file.setText(pickFile.getSelectedFile().getName());
                    directory.setText(pickFile.getCurrentDirectory().toString());
                }
                if (dialog == JFileChooser.CANCEL_OPTION) {
                    GUI.this.file.setText("You pressed cancel");
                    directory.setText("");
                }
                try {
                    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
                    BSTFunctions bstf = new BSTFunctions();
                    while (scanner.hasNext()) {
                        bstf.insert(bstf.ROOT, scanner.next().toLowerCase().trim(), 1);
                    }

                    bstf.wordCount(bstf.ROOT);
                    bstf.listInOrder(bstf.ROOT);

                    scanner.close();
                } catch (IOException e1) {

                    results.append("\n\u2022YOU MUST SELECT A FILE TO CONTINUE");
                }
```

Comment: You probably need to show your insertNode code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make `BSTFunctions bstf = new BSTFunctions();` a field of your `GUI` class instead of declaring it inside `actionPerformed`. If you declare it inside the method, you'll be starting a new one from scratch everytime that method runs.

```
class GUI extends JFrame {
    private final BSTFunctions bstf = new BSTFunctions();
    // everything else
}
```

Comment: so after the````int dialog = pickFile.showOpenDialog(GUI.this)````

Comment: @ryanwilliams I've updated the answer. It should be before the outer-most if-else loop.

Comment: Ive updated it and no luck. If youre willing to maybe you could take a look at my actionlistener class and see if you see the issue https://gist.github.com/DanielHenrichs/48cd1e6b8d29216d8ddbba973f05de94

Comment: additionally, if i need to send the code for the BST functions i can do that.

Comment: i have not, it continues to erase the tree. Here are some links to my code if you want to take a look Here is the code for my GUI

https://gist.github.com/DanielHenrichs/42d7cdff508af4034ea5e3b46eda9b06

And here is the code fro my BST functions:

https://gist.github.com/DanielHenrichs/5b9fa09fadf93cb17c73a7e272f66d8b